# constructing infinitely long path

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

I would like to show that $\displaystyle \left|\int_C{{z^{-4}}} ~dz \right| \le 4\sqrt2$ where $C$ is ANY path between $z = i$ and $z = 1$.

Show that a path $C$ where the length of that path is infinity or approaches infinity produces a maximum approaching $4 \sqrt2$. I haven't the slightest clue how to construct an infinitely long path.

Comment: $z^{-4}$ is very much _not_ holomorphic. It has a pole of order $4$ at $0$.

Comment: Do you mean paths from $z = i$ to $z = 1$? Clearly $z^{-4}$ isn't holomorphic (it has a pole of order 4 at 0).

Comment: ah. sorry for the confusion. correct me if i'm wrong but a path independent function must be holomorphic.

Comment: $i \le z \le 1$ makes no sense: $\mathbb C$ has no standard order relation.

Comment: Any two paths connecting $1$ and $i$ form a loop (possibly enclosing $0$) however the residue picked up is $0$ since it's not a simple pole.

Comment: can you describe "loop"?

Comment: In muzzlator's comment, the "since it's not a simple pole" can be misleading.  In general, a non-simple pole may well have a non-zero residue.  But the function in this question does have a residue of 0 at its only pole, so the integral is independent of the path as long as the path doesn't go through the pole.

Comment: simply for clarification, the double bars is meant to imply the magnitude of the function rather than simply absolute value.

Comment: What's the difference in your mind between "magnitude" and "absolute value"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the pole of $z^{-4}$ has residue $0$, the integral is in fact path-independent.
Also, you can write down an explicit antiderivative.
You do have to assume the path does not hit $0$.

EDIT: The second part is simply false.  The integral on any path from $i$ to $1$ is 
$(i-1)/3$ which has absolute value $\sqrt{2}/3$.  There is no way to get anything close to $4 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis) i retrieved the following formula for calculating residue of poles of order $n$, $Res(f,c) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z\to ~c}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(z-c)^n ~f(z)$ for the calculation of residue for $f(z) = z^{-4} $ i computed that the residue does not exist? is that correct?

Comment: No, the residue is $0$.  It is a pole of order $n=4$, and 
$\dfrac{d^3}{dz^3} (z^4 \cdot z^{-4}) = 0$.